# How can I stagger these HTML elements vertically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I want to make a grid have certain columns staggered, like this:

[image: staggered columns]

Currently I can only get the 4th element to line up so it's below 2 (with a `clear: left;`). **[This can be seen in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeonardChallis/s9KDC/1/)**.

I'm not sure if this is possible without absolute positioning or at best relative position to the `#wrapper` element. I'm not totally against ideas that need `javascript`, because in fact the above jsFiddle is a very simplified version of a layout that relies on `jQuery` to display properly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section>
        <p>1</p>
    </section>

    <section id="staggered">
        <p>2</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <p>3</p>
    </section>

    <section id="new-row">
        <p>4</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <p>5</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <p>6</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #FFCC66;
    float: left;
}

section#staggered {
    margin-top: 35px;
}

section#new-row {
    clear: left;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 360px;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you have control over the way it's been put there. But i would make 3 columns with 2 sections in it instead of all the sections in one block.

Comment: You also have the slightly dubious method of giving `section`'s 4 and 6 negative `margin-top` as a last resort.

Comment: I'm beginning to think columns are the way to go - I just thought there might be a more elegant way of doing it. I hate wrapper divs, never mind columns withing wrappers within... ;)

Comment: @YaMo I'm intrigued. Would you care to answer the question with a demo, and possibly remark on why using such a method may not be a good idea, so I can weight it up versus the column idea?

Comment: @LeonardChallis It's just dessign logic. I've learned, after a couple time dessigning web pages (I'm not a master) that you can't "tell" to CSS: `HEY! CSS! I want a div.... HERE!!!! (blow to the screen exactly where you want your element)`. You can check it in many web pages that uses divs to build tables, menus, etc. You can see something like `<div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><span>Hello World</span></div></div>...` So, you have to first build what you want in a paper or something like that, exactly what you want and what you will need.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX Yes, but to me that's both ugly and hard to maintain. I suppose that using `div`s to aid styling isn't totally out of the question (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) but was looking to avoid that kind of thing.

Comment: @LeonardChallis Yeah, if you take a look at source code maybe it would be ugly, but I think that this is the way to work with web pages. You must contain everything into something. To show you an example, today I was doing an icon button and the icon is a `<span>` with a background. I wanted to put it "inside" (`position:absolute`) an `<input type="text">` and fill all height of the input. I had to put that `<span>` into another `<span>` and set it a padding to center the icon and set a height to fill up full input height. It's hard to evade containers inside other containers, etc.

Comment: @LeonardChallis [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/s9KDC/6/). Even though it's a valid part of the W3C CSS recommendation, it's a nightmare for maintainability on large projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9KDC/7/)**.

I've divided your sections into "columns" to work much easier. You could divide it into more `<div>` so you can specify a "table" with `row => column`. If you prefer it as a table, I can edit the demo to it, but I thought this was enough for your example.

The reason to use only "columns" was because if you want to define it as containers table, you must add `lower` class to both divs, working as columns, containing `2` and `5`

Comment: No, definitely don't want a table, but this solution is probably the way forward. I'd be interested in seeing other ideas, but doesn't seem many are available! :)